# push_back of an integer doesn't work on my vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, std, push-back

I am trying to push back 3 vectors in parallel, and when I get to `push_back()` into the string vector, I get this error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::string, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::string>]" matches the argument listC/C++(304)
ask3.cpp(38, 8): argument types are: (int)
ask3.cpp(38, 8): object type is: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>
```

Here is the chunk of code that I'm in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length, count = 0, moviecount = 0, spacecount = 0;
    ;
    vector<int> status, price;
    vector<string> movies;
    string FileName, text, line, dummy;

    FileName = "MovieList.txt";

    ifstream InFile;
    InFile.open(FileName);
    while (!InFile.eof()) {
        getline(InFile, line);
        text += line + "\n";
    }
    cout << text;

    length = text.length();
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        if (text[i] == ' ') {
            spacecount++;
        }
    }
    if (spacecount == 2) {
        moviecount = 1;
    }
    else if (spacecount > 2) {
        int temp = spacecount;
        temp = temp - 2;
        temp = temp / 3;
        moviecount = 1 + temp;
    }
    movies.push_back(moviecount); //<-- problem line
    status.push_back(moviecount);
    price.push_back(moviecount);
}
```

Comment: Side note: your usage of `while(!InFile.eof())` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). You should check if reading succeeded *before* using what are "read".

Comment: `moviecount` is an `int`. `movies` is a `vector<string>`. There's no implicit conversion from an `int` to `std::string`. It's not clear what you want to be happening here, but that's why it's refusing to compile.

Comment: @Dami Karv What is unclear with the error message?!

Comment: Aside: why do you need 3 vectors that each contain the same 1 `int`? What are you trying to do with this program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movies` is a vector of `string`, so you cannot push `int` directly.

If you are using C++11 or later, you can use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert integers to strings.

Another way to convert integers to strings is using [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) like this:

```cpp
std::stringstream ss;
ss << moviecount;
movies.push_back(ss.str());
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I hope this question can be useful because googling it directly doesn't get many results.

Comment: "*Another way to convert integers to strings is ...*" - `std::ostringstream` would be more appropriate in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to push `int` values in a vector `movies` that is initialized to store `string` values.

Not sure what you are trying to get out of this code but
You can either change the vector's type to int like so : `vector<int> movies` or convert int to string using [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) before push_back() like so :
`movies.push_back(std::to_string(moviecount))`